# Attribute Error When Using Report Lab Python Library

Tags: python

When using report lab to convert a text file to a PDF, I am getting following error:

> canvas.drawString(15, i, linea.strip())
>   AttributeError: module 'reportlab.pdfgen.canvas' has no attribute 'drawString'

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried reinstalling report lab, but this did not fix the issue.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from PIL import Image
    while numeroLinea < len(lineas):
        if numeroLinea - len(lineas) < 60:  # I'm gonna write every 60 lines because I need it like that
            i = 750
            for linea in lineas[numeroLinea:numeroLinea + 60]:
                canvas.drawString(15, i, linea.strip())
                numeroLinea += 1
                i -= 12
            canvas.showPage()
        else:
            i = 750
            for linea in lineas[numeroLinea:]:
                canvas.drawString(15, i, linea.strip())
                numeroLinea += 1
                i -= 12
            canvas.showPage()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `canvas` is a module that was imported from reportlab.pdfgen. This module contains class `Canvas`. You should create an object of this class to get access to the methods of this class, such as `drawString()`, `showPage()` and others. For example:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

PATH_TO_PDF = '/media/data/sample.pdf' # path to your pdf file
can = canvas.Canvas(PATH_TO_PDF)
can.drawString(...)
can.showPage(...)
```